# how to forward touch event in react-native?

Tags: react-native, gesture, touch-event

Please see the demo code [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/bD_Evg).

If i begin touch in blue view, scroll view not being scrolled, how should I do to make this work?

Or if blue view is under the scroll view (and the content's background color is transparent), how should I do to handle touch event when I click the blue view?

Comment: Whats your exact requirement ? do u have any sample mockup or something ?

Comment: Hi @Rajesh I want to make a view like iOS tableview, but the different is the header is stay on top, and handle click event to do some suff

Comment: is https://rnplay.org/apps/80QzJA what you are looking for ?